# MySQL Join - return results from one table based on data in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables.

CLIENTS TABLE

- id
- email

DOMAINS TABLE

- id
- hosting
- client_id

I need to return all the clients.email where domains.hosting =  given_id.

--

```
SELECT 
  clients.email 
FROM 
  clients
INNER JOIN
  domains
  ON domains.client_id = clients.id
    AND domains.hosting_id = given_id
```

--

Is that correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `given_id` is not a column in one of your tables, your query is fine.  However, it is not clear from the query that no duplicates are being returned.  This would be a particular issue if you were looking for multiple "given id"s at the same time.

An alternative way of writing the query is to use `exists`:

```
SELECT c.email 
FROM clients c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM domains d
              WHERE d.client_id = c.id AND
                    d.hosting_id = given_id
             );
```